# rsync error: syntax or usage error

Tags: ssh, putty, rsync

I am trying to copy local windows system folder files to remote server. tried below command in ssh using putty :

```
rsync -avz -e 'ssh' C:\wamp64\www\magento3 user@111.11.11.111:/var/www/html
```

but it gave error  :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are first connecting to your server using putty and then executing the rsync command.
In that case you are executung the command **from** your server, ie. the source directory is **in** your server and destination is also your server.

In fact rsync is not a Windows tool. You can use a windows packaged version: [cwRsync](https://www.itefix.net/cwrsync?module=pagemaster&PAGE_user_op=view_page&PAGE_id=6).